# Spring MVC Binding

Tags: java, spring, data-binding, spring-mvc

I am not sure if this is possible, but I need to do some odd binding with Spring MVC.  We have to dynamically generate a page which is a precursor to running some reports.  Different reports will have different criteria which are available restrict what data is shown on the report.

I was hoping that I could do something like this:

```
public interface ReportingStrategy extends Serializable {
    public String getReportingCriteria(); //Each subclass will generate the SQL needed
}

public class DateLimitingStrategy implements ReportingStrategy {

    private Date startDate;
    public Date getStartDate() { return startDate; }
    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) { this.startDate = startDate; }

    private Date endDate;
    public Date getEndDate() { return endDate; }
    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) { this.endDate = endDate; }

    public String getReportingCriteria() {
        //Generate SQL for date range (where necessary)
    }
}

public class SortingStrategy impelements ReportingStrategy {
    public String sortValue;
    public String getSortValue() { return this.sortValue; }
    public void setSortValue(String sortValue) { this.sortValue = sortValue; }
}
```

So it seems like a pretty simple idea.

On my controller side I'd like to be able to bind to a list of these on a post.  I'm able to generate the HTML which should make this necessary, but the binding isn't working properly.  Here's a basis of my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView(@RequestParam("reportName") String reportName) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("showReportingStrategies");
    mav.addObject("backingObject", new BackingObject(reportName));
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView(@ModelAttribute("backingObject") BackingObject bo, BindingResult result) {
    //More logic here   
}

public class BackingObject implements Serializable {
    private List<ReportingStrategy> reportingStrategies;
    public void setReportingStratgies(List<ReportingStrategy> reportingStrategies) {
        this.reportingStrategies = reportingStrategies;
    }
    public List<ReportingStrategy> getReportingStrategies() { return this.reportingStrategies; }
}
```

Is this even possible by extending PropertyEditorSupport and doing InitBinder magic?

Comment: Are the types of reporting strategies known at the time the page is loaded, or is the user choosing them?

Comment: They will be known, just dynamic in that report A might have a date limiting strategy and report B might have both. The constructor for the BackingObject will look them up in the DB (not shown)

Answer (score 1):

The far and away simplest thing is to use `@SessionAttributes` to put your backing object on the session.  This way the concrete types are present at bind time.  The binder doesn't need to be able to figure out what implementer of `ReportingStrategy` to use, they're already there.  The server side state may be an issue for you of course, and if you're using raw MVC without webflow and your application supports multi-tabbed use, you'll need to handle that as always.